# I hava a sql that work fine in mysql 5.7.35, but couldn't work in 8.0.22

Tags: mysql

Here is my sql sentence

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO user_predicts (id,points,rank,rid,uid,win_count)
VALUES (0,0,0,1,1016,0)
```

All the fields in this table is int
But in 8.0.22, it just give me this bottom line:

> Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rank,rid,uid,win_count) VALUES (0,0,0,1,1016,0)' at line 1

But this sql works fine in 5.7.35

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RANK` is a reserved word in MySQL v8, added since version 8.0.2. You can't use it in query unless you wrap it with backticks (`). Try this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO user_predicts (id,points,`rank`,rid,uid,win_count) VALUES 
(0,0,0,1,1016,0)
```

[Here's MySQL documentation about reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-R). Please note that all words appended with `(R)` in the docs must wrap in backticks if you want to use it. Either that, or just change you column name to `Ranks`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `RANK` keyword as field name. In MySQL 8.0, the word is used as a window function `RANK()`. You must replace the field name `rank` with a different name.